# Pandas how to check values of specific columns is same

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5 columns in data-frame called `'A','B','C','D','E'`. I want to filter data-frame where values of columns `'A','C'and 'E'` are equal.

I have done the following :

```
OutputDF = DF[DF['A']==DF['C']==DF['E']]
```

Its giving error as follows:

```
 ValueError: Truth value of series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.boolean,a.item(),a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare all filtered columns by list by first column of list by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and test if all values are `True` by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  1  2  1  4  1
2  2  2  2  4  2

L = ['A','C','E']
df = df[df[L].eq(df[L[0]], axis=0).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
1  1  2  1  4  1
2  2  2  2  4  2
```

Answer (score 3):

To address why this happens:

```
import pandas as pd
DF = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2],
                   "C": [1, 2],
                   "E": [1, 2],
                   })
OutputDF = DF[DF['A']==DF['C']==DF['E']]
#ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
```

The issue is that, due to how operator chaining works, `DF['A']==DF['C']==DF['E']` is being interpreted as

```
DF['A']==DF['C'] and DF['C']==DF['E']
```

Essentially, we are attempting to do a boolean `and` between two Series, and thus we see our error. Since a Series should be giving multiple values, while `and` expects a single value on both sides of the operator, Thus there is ambiguity on how to reduce the Series on either sides to a single value.

If you wanted to write the condition correctly, you could use bitwise and (&) instead as follows (the brackets are important with bitwise &):

```
OutputDF = DF[(DF['A']==DF['C']) & (DF['C']==DF['E'])]
```